# When trying to run ANY keras code R session aborts

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have just downloaded and installed the CPU version of Keras by running in R:

```
> install.packages("keras")
> library(keras)
> install_keras(method = "virtualenv")
```

This runs and installs successfully with no issues yet when I simply run

```
> keras::backend()
```

or any other keras line of code, I get this error every time:

```
/Users/michael/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: 
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float`
   to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as 
  `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
   from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.

*** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x10e9a7dd9, cause 'illegal opcode'

Traceback:
 1: .Call(`_reticulate_py_module_import`, module, convert)
 2: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
 3: import(module)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch(import(module), error = clear_error_handler())
 8: py_resolve_module_proxy(x)
 9: `$.python.builtin.module`(keras, backend)
10: keras$backend
11: backend()
```

I am running R version 3.4.3 and Python version 2.7.10

Here is my CPU info as I know that this error may be related to the processor:

```
Apple: AUDynamicsProcessor:
Apple: AUVoiceProcessor:
  Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed: 3.06 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated. I've already tried reinstalling keras and R but to no avail :(

Comment: Have you tried installing Anaconda first? I see you're on macOS but on Windows the only supported install option is with conda. I wonder if this was a design decision because conda wraps up all the correct versions of the various necessary packages. Although it is true that the actual error you're getting is probably C/C++, I wonder if you have the wrong version of some packages or something got compiled incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: (I could also be *totally* wrong, but it's worth a shot. I have found setting up the deep learning libraries correctly very challenging. I would help more if I could replicate your error. Good luck!)